# Can I create two different keyboard shortcuts for the same command?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, preferences

The Preferences.app > Keyboard > Shortcuts pane allows for the creation of shortcuts to activate menu commands. However if that menu command already has a keyboard then that shortcut is overridden by the new shortcut.

For example, the Paste menu command - I would prefer to use more than one shortcut to execute that command.

- Command + V
- Shift + Insert

How do I prevent the second addition from removing the first that so that I can create as many keyboard shortcut aliases as I want for a given menu command?

Comment: But what should happen if you enter a given shortcut? Should all commands be executed simultaneously? Downvoters, please leave feedback on how to improve the question!

Comment: @n1000 Other way round, I think: Several shortcuts for the same command, so one can use Cmd-V *and* Shift-Insert to paste, for example.

Comment: @nohillside Exactly!.

Comment: I've never seen an Insert key on an Apple keyboard.

Comment: @SteveMoser Any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Look into using the application "Keyboard Maestro" as a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Would you consider editing this to show how the maestro would handle two combinations on one item?